# What is the function of "kill -1 -9" command?

Tags: command-line, 17.10, gnome-terminal, 16.10

I am a newbie in Ubuntu, I have learned a command-

**kill -1 -9** - send signal to process.

Plzz tell me what type of **signal** it is talking about and in the command what **-1 -9** means?

Comment: Also have a look at `man 7 signal` which describes the signals and signal handling.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect the command you *really* learned of was

```
kill -9 -1
```

According to `man kill`, the format of the `kill` command is

```
kill [options] <pid> [...]
```

so `-9` is an option and `-1` is a PID or *process identifier*. As noted in the man page,

> ```
>                                                                A PID of -1
>    is special; it indicates all processes except the kill  process  itself
>    and init.
> ```

while for an explanation of the signal values, you can either run `man 7 signal` or get a synopsis from the `kill` command itself with the `-l` option:

```
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGBUS       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGUSR2     13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD     18) SIGCONT     19) SIGSTOP     20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGURG      24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO       30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS      34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```

So, as noted in the `EXAMPLES` section

```
EXAMPLES
       kill -9 -1
              Kill all processes you can kill.
```

The *"you can"* here is an oblique reference to privileges - in practice, ordinary users will not be able to kill processes that they do not own.

---

The *actual* command given in your question would attempt to send signal 1 (`SIGHUP`) to process -9 (which is not a valid PID) so will just return an error:

```
$ kill -1 -9
-bash: kill: (-9) - No such process
```

Comment: I think that the writer is wrong because I wrote the command as it is written on the cheat sheet.

Comment: Is " -1 -9 " and " -9 -1 " in kill command both are same or not?

Comment: @coding_ninza no they are not: the first one (attempts to) send signal `1` to a process whose PID is `-9` (which is not a valid PID) whereas the second sends signal `9` to all process except itself and the `init` process, as explained in the manual page.

Comment: oh, ok I guess that command was written incorrectly on the cheat sheet.

Comment: @steeldriver  In the real question the `-9` is a command-line argument and 9 is the `PID` try it. it works. `-1` is not negative 1 but an argument 1 ( signal ).

Comment: @T.Obadiah I **did** try it - I even posted the result in my answer (`-bash: kill: (-9) - No such process`). What *"real question"* are you referring to?

Comment: @steeldriver `No such process.` because there is no process with id 9.   But try an actual process id in its place.

Comment: @steeldriver Actually `-9` as `PID` is not a `PID` but a `PGID` (process group id). So `kill -1 -9` sends `SIGHUP` to all processes in group `9`.

Answer (score -1):

```
kill -1 -9
```

sends a `SIGHUB` to process with id `9`

The first argument `1` is a numerical equivalent to a specific signal(`SIGHUB`) and the second `9` is a  program`PID`.

**SIGBU** is describe as *Hangup detected on controlling terminal or death of controlling process*

On terminal `kill -l` list the various Linux signals and `man 7 signal` gives some descriptive overview of the various signals

Comment: Here what "1" and "9" stands for

Comment: Hmm the would be `kill -1 9` NOT `kill -1 -9`. I agree with steeldriver: it probably is `kill -9 -1` since `-1` is a special case. `-9` is not a option, nor a valid process number since those are all positive except for `-1`

Comment: @coding_ninza Arguments passed in this way. The 1st represent `signal` type and the second `PID`